# Part of bottom tab bar is hidden

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native, tabs, react-navigation

I use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) for routing and navigation in a react native project. I have a bottom tab bar component, which is partially hidden in Android.

**TabNavigator**

```
...    
{
        lazy: true,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        animationEnabled: false,
        initialRouteName: 'Schedule',
        swipeEnabled: false,
        tabBarOptions: {
          showIcon: true,
          showLabel: true,
          allowFontScaling: true,
          upperCaseLabel: false,
          activeTintColor: Colors.white,
          inactiveTintColor: Colors.darkGrey,
          indicatorStyle: {
            // backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          },
          labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: '500',
          },
          style: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.darkBlue,
            height: 50,
          },
          iconStyle: {
            height: TAB_ICON_SIZE,
            width: TAB_ICON_SIZE,
            padding: 0,
            margin: 0,
          },
        },
      },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was `margin: 8` for `labelStyle`.

Changing labelStyle fixed that:

```
labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: '500',
        margin: 2,
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following alignSelf property to iconStyle and make sure that TAB_ICON_SIZE is not greater that 24. Because it's following material guid designs in react-native android.

```
iconStyle: {
        height: TAB_ICON_SIZE,
        width: TAB_ICON_SIZE,
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
        alignSelf: 'center'
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, `TAB_ICON_SIZE` is `20` and when I added `alignSelf: 'center'`, nothing changed